# Digital Signature Standard Office 2003

Tags: ms-office, digital-signature

Anybody know which standard use Office 2003 to sign a document?

1. Office 2007 uses **XML-DSig**
2. Office 2010 uses **XAdES**
3. Office 2003 ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK they used their own custom scheme, as Office 2003 format was binary, not OOXML

Comment: Yes, they used their own custom scheme. By the way, I guess that Open XML isn't approved standard yet.

Comment: If you meant OOXML, it has been approved as a standard (unfortunately).